# One data lookup in another csv file and print first data values with lookup values

Tags: python

I am trying to below file operation using python

input 1: unix shell cat command given below data file name: input1.txt

```
11/13/2020 07:41:09 TREE count1: id1 green001
11/13/2020 07:43:09 TREE count1: id1 black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09 TREE count1: id2 black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09 PLAN count1: id3 green002
```

Lookup data: file name: lookup.csv

```
ID,item,message
id1,item1,message 1
id2,item2,message 2
id3,item3,message 3
```

Need output like: where id field in [id1, id2, id3, etc ..in] input1 lookup in ID filed in lookup table.\

Output.txt

```
Time,Type,counts,id,item,message,colour
11/13/2020 07:41:09,TREE,count1,id1,item1,message 1,green001
11/13/2020 07:43:09,TREE,count1,id1,item1,message 1,black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09,TREE,count1,id2,item2,message 2,black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09,PLAN,count1,id3,item3,message 3,green002
```

I've been trying to use this code, but I am getting errors.

```
r = pandas.read_csv(file1, sep=' ', index_col='ID')
with open('/home/s/lookup.csv','r') as w:
    x = pandas.read_csv(w)
    # w is not indexable
    col = w['ID']
    for line in w:
        # w is not a table.
        for col in w:
            for row in r:
                if row in col:
                    print(line)
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You didnt tell us what errors you got.  If youre using Pandas, you can join both DataFrames together based on Ids and then dump it back out to a file.   Are you errors related to the commented "w is not indexable" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` can merge the data for you. When you merge "on" a column, the column value for any row is used to get the columns from the other dataframe. You may have to fiddle with column names and order, and then write csv when you are done.

```
import pandas as pd

# read input and remove spurious : at end of count
input1 = pd.read_csv("input1.csv", sep=' ',
         names=["date","time", "tree","count","ID", "info"])
input1["count"] = input1["count"].apply(lambda s:s[:-1])

# read lookup and merge
lookup = pd.read_csv("lookup.csv")
merged = input1.merge(lookup, on="ID")

# collapse time and date to single column
merged["time"] = merged["date"] + " " + merged["time"]
del merged["date"]

# output
print(merged)
merged.to_csv("testme.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but date and time are together and I have : extra vale in input which need to handle.

Comment: I trimmed out the ":" with `input1["count"].apply(lambda s:s[:-1])`. Since date and time are separated by a space, they will be different columns in the dataframe. I'll add some code to combine them.

Comment: How to save target as csv file where date and time should not separated by ,

Comment: Its in the example. `merged["date"] + " " + merged["time"]` created a single column (and the delete date). It will write to csv without the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
lookup = pd.read_csv("lookup.csv")
input = []
with open("input1.txt") as fp:
  d,t,tr,co,key,color = [x for x in fp.read().split(" ") if x != '']
  input.append({"Time": " ".join([d,t]), "Type": tr, "Counts": co[:-1], "ID": key, "Colour": color})

# co[:-1] removes the trailing ":" from the Counts columns.
rslt = pd.DataFrame(input)

merged = pd.merge(left=lookup, right=rslt, left_on="ID", right_on="ID")

print(merged)
```

Comment: thanks for help! but I am getting below error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 5, in <module>
    d,t,tr,co,key,color = [x for x in fp.read().split(" ") if x != '']
ValueError: too many values to unpack